# Div Floating left goes down

Tags: html, css, css-float

I will have a three child div's in a wrapper, two of them will need to float right and one will always float left(one which has `.main` class). you can have a look at my HTML structure in the fiddle

[My Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/saikiranmarripati/w6qqca70/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="child"> 
        This is initiator
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        This is second joinee
    </div>
    <div class="main child">
        This is third joinee
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrap{
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
}
.child:nth-child(even){
  background:red;
}
.child:nth-child(odd){
  background:green;
}
.child{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  clear:right;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.main{
  height: 400px!important;
  width: 400px!important;
  float:left!important;
  clear:none!important;
  background:yellow !important;
}
```

But the Left floated Div always comes down. can some one help me understanding this behaviour.

**Note:** I don't want to change my HTML structure.

Comment: Just change *.main*'s `float` to `none`: `float:none!important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to the `main` class in your css file:

```
.main{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: but that creates a margin on right side of left floated div, why is that

Comment: Look at update fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/saikiranmarripati/w6qqca70/3/